# how to access my bean class defined in netbeans using libraries can be used in main method of new project

Tags: java, javabeans

```
public class BeanClass
{
public BeanClass (){}
public void setName (String name){
this.name =name;
}
public String getName ()
{
return this.name;
}
}
```

I want to retrieve above methods in main metod of other new project using net beans. I have defied above class in library class and was added under bean tree of pallet

Answer (score 0):

In another class:

```
import your.package.BeanClass;

BeanClass beanclass = new BeanClass();
beanClass.setName("bob");

String beanName = beanClass.getName();
```

You have to set the project as a library, and add it as a reference to your new project, alternatively, you could export a reference `jar`, and add that as in import to your new project.